# Relationship normalization in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, normalization

[image]

I want to know should I remove `PersonTypeId` from `Persons` table or is it a good idea to have it in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it there so that you know what PersonType is Person is. Without it, you don’t know.

Normalisation means that you don’t have `PersonTypeName` in the `Persons` table. But `PersonTypeID` is fine and what you need.

Comment: @rob_farley When we need `Customers` we can join `Persons` table by `Customers` and get all customers without needing `PersonTypeId` in `Persons` table. Despite being so helpful having `PersonTypeId` in `Persons` table, I am not sure about performance and integrity of data

Comment: Oh, is PersonTypeID telling you that a particular person is a Customer or a Driver or a Seller? In that case, scrap the PersonType table completely. Otherwise you can’t have a person be a Driver and a Seller, only one.

Comment: @rob_farley you pointed to a very important point. What if I want a person just have one role. Do you think in this situation `PersonTypes` table isn't helpful.

I think by having `PersonTypeId` I can get persons faster just by a WHERE clause, but without it I have to join tables each time i need a specific person. 
But I am not sure about if it is a Bad Practice.

Comment: I think I’d be tempted to just have three tables, and scrap the Persons table. But it depends on how many columns you have in Persons. If it’s just Name, just include that in each of the others.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Rob Farley](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4103/rob-farley)'s answer, a common pattern to guarantee that `PersonTypeId` is correct, is to introduce a superkey in `PERSONS`:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT ... 
    UNIQUE (PersonTypeId, Id);

ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT ...   
    CHECK ( PersonTypeId in ('C','D','S'));
```

and extend each of the sub-types with the type attribute. Now Customers can reference this super-key:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
( CustomerID ... NOT NULL -- is this needed?
, PersonId ... NOT NULL
, PersonTypeId CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'C' NOT NULL
, ...
,     CHECK ( PersonTypeId = 'C' )
,     FOREIGN KEY ( PersonTypeId, PersonId)
         REFERENCES Persons (PersonTypeId, Id)
);
```

A couple of DBMS (Sybase?) allow `SELECT` in CHECK constraints. It is then not necessary to add the attribute in the sub-tables. Most DBMS don't allow this though, so it is fairly common to do like above.